# Model Path not found in Sagemaker Inference

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, fastapi, amazon-sagemaker, inference

I'm trying to perform pose-associated activities as part of inferencing. I'm using Fastapi to perform inferencing on Sagemaker by following https://sii.ua/blog/en/deploying-custom-models-on-aws-sagemaker-using-fastapi/

I have a bunch of pre-models in here which i have stored as a tar file on S3.
Cmd used to tar the files:

```
cd opt/ml/
tar -czvf pre-models.tar.gz pre-models
```

[image]

In my code, i have set model path as '**ml/pre_models**/(sub-dir varies as per requirement)'
However, Sagemaker cannot find the model path. I get this line in cloudwatch:

> "Fix path to models/ ml/pre_models/models"

I tried ls, and i can't see pre-models files in there.

Answer (score 0):

For future self who lands here...

I had my code in **/opt/ml/** and models in **pre_models/**

**Sagemaker Inference** creates a directory **model/** to store the S3 models. So the final path appeared as :

```
/opt/ml/model/pre_models
```

To trace this path just keep on printing the directory structure from your code (in my case "invocations" API method

```
print(os.system("ls"))
print(os.system("ls /opt/ml"))
```